# Schtask command to be used with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a cmd file containg this

```
schtasks /Change /TN "Mytask" /ENABLE
```

How can I rewrite this into powershell instead?

Comment: check out "Schedule.Service" Com-Object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383607(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have a [ScheduledTasks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816(v=wps.630).aspx) module on Windows 8+. On older systems you must use `schtasks` or 3thd party module.

To be honest, there is no need to rewrite this just for the sake of being purist.

Comment: One could also use the [API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, I do agree that there's no need to rewrite a working `schtasks.exe` commandline just for the halibut. Running external commands usually works just fine from PowerShell.

Comment: There might be problem with logging tho... And posh native variant is FAR more readable. To bad it doesn't work on older systems (IMO very lame on MS ). Plus, some API non often used features are not present in module.

Comment: BTW, COM uneasiness with usage is one of the reasons Powershell is created. COM usage simply sux compared to native Posh.

Comment: I've used the Task Scheduler 2.0 API before and it works just fine. It also can do things that `schtasks.exe` can't, so it's a fallback for pre-Win8 systems.

Comment: Good to know, however COM is simply _Meh_. This kind of thing should be producable as oneliner which *is* the case on linux with `at` and with `schtasks`. Even Powershell module is too verbose for my taste.